# LocalStorage in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to `set` some items into localStorage in an Next js app but its not working and i get nothing saved in localStorage.

This is my code:

```
function AsyncForm(props) {

const [job, setJob] = useState(
    typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? localStorage.getItem("job")
      : typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("job"))
      : null
  );

  const [caption, setCaption] = useState(
    typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? localStorage.getItem("caption")
      : typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("caption"))
      : null
  );

  const [transcription, setTranscription] = useState(
    typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? localStorage.getItem("transcription")
      : typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("transcription"))
      : null
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!job) return;

    const url = `api/caption/${job.id}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((caption) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("caption", JSON.stringify(caption));
        setCaption(caption);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [job]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!job) return;

    const transUrl = `/api/transcription/${job.id}/text`;
    fetch(transUrl)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((transcription) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem(
          "transcription",
          JSON.stringify(transcription)
        );
        setTranscription(transcription);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [job]);

return (
    <>
      {job && transcription ? (
        <p style={{ color: "white", paddingTop: "200px" }}>{transcription}</p>
      ) : (
        <p style={{ color: "white", paddingTop: "200px" }}>loading...</p>
      )}

      {job && caption ? (
        <div style={{ color: "white" }}>
          <MediaPlayer src={job.media_url} caption={caption} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <img alt="hero" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300" />
      )}
      <div style={{ color: "white" }}>
        <MediaUploader />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

}
```

Anyone have any idea of what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked if your code runs past `if (!job) return;` in the `useEffect` blocks? The `useEffect` in your case will only run if the `job` state is set, but I don't see where it gets set initially. Your `[job, setJob] = useState(...)` block will initially return `null` which means the code in your `useEffect` won't get executed (past `if(!job) return`)

Comment: i think i have to fetch the `job` data from the `/api/job/` file via getServerSideProps somehow but don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

i think no need to use `.then((res) => res.text())` because you want to convert to json you can put it in the header `content-type : application/json` and in the then function put console.log() to show you the result if there is no data check the api in insomnia or postman to check if you are getting any result

Answer (score 0):

Next Js uses a node server that doesn't communicate with the browser.

I recommend to uses a library nookies for save data in cookies and get the data.

https://npm.io/package/nookies